# How to read a CSV file having JSON array inside to get Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a file "orders.csv" of the following structure:

```
order_id,order_date,user_id,store_id,product_info
1,2022-01-11,948,6,"[{'product_id': 155, 'product_price': 9948.590055202974, 'product_comission': 75, 'comission_is_percent': True, 'count': 1}]"
2,2022-01-11,1074,6,"[{'product_id': 352, 'product_price': 19451.45856712592, 'product_comission': 5, 'comission_is_percent': True, 'count': 1}, {'product_id': 1902, 'product_price': 19593.205091541993, 'product_comission': 7000, 'comission_is_percent': False, 'count': 1}]"
3,2022-01-11,3361,6,"[{'product_id': 2004, 'product_price': 19335.038737925435, 'product_comission': 5, 'comission_is_percent': True, 'count': 1}]"
```

What I need is to get a DataFrame with JSON strings in one separated column.

I tried just to read the file:

```
import pandas as pd

orders = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')
```

but had this error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 14 fields in line 3, saw 19
```

Probably, python counts commas inside JSON part as a CSV separator. However, I thought that quotation marks near JSON string would be enough to convert it into a python string.
Unfortunately, I found nothing to solve this problem.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error with your sample data.  The `product_info` column is properly quoted and your code example reads `[3 rows x 5 columns]`.  However, the data *in* column 5 is not JSON.  It is the `repr()` of a Python list of dictionaries. The clue is the dictionary keys are single-quoted; JSON strings are double-quoted.  `ast.literal_eval()` could be used to parse it into an actual Python object.

Comment: The problem was solved by using Jupyter instead of Colab. So the only issue apparently was Colab but still I can not understand why exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You got it done with Jupyter instead of Colab.
That's a workaround, not a solution.

Here is the solution that works with Colab:

```
order_id  order_date user_id store_id                                       product_info
0        1  2022-01-11     948        6  [{'product_id': 155, 'product_price': 9948.590...
1        2  2022-01-11    1074        6  [{'product_id': 352, 'product_price': 19451.45...
2        3  2022-01-11    3361        6  [{'product_id': 2004, 'product_price': 19335.0...
```

```
"""
Special characters are: comma (delimiter), line feeds (end of row).
Cells enclosed in double quotes allow literal special characters inside them.
"""
import pandas as pd

def stringToList(input_string):
    input_string = input_string + '\n'
    return_list = []
    temp_list = []
    temp_string = ""
    specialchar_enabled = True
    for x in range(len(input_string)):
        temp_string = temp_string + input_string[x]
        if input_string[x]==',':
            if specialchar_enabled:
                temp_string = temp_string[:-1]
                temp_list.append(temp_string.strip())
                temp_string = ""
        if input_string[x]=='\n':
            if specialchar_enabled:
                temp_string = temp_string[:-1]
                temp_list.append(temp_string)
                temp_string = ""
                return_list.append(temp_list)
                temp_list = []
        if input_string[x]=='"':
            if (len(temp_string.lstrip()) == 1):
                temp_string = temp_string[:-1]
                specialchar_enabled = False
            next_nonwhitespace_char = None
            counter = 1
            while next_nonwhitespace_char == None:
                if input_string[x+counter] not in [' ','\t']:
                    next_nonwhitespace_char = counter
                else:
                    counter = counter + 1
            if input_string[x+next_nonwhitespace_char] in ['\n',',']:
                temp_string = temp_string[:-1]
                specialchar_enabled = True
    return_list_2 = []
    for x in (return_list):
        if len(x) > 1:
            return_list_2.append(x)
    return return_list_2

text_file = open("orders.csv", "r")
content = text_file.read()
text_file.close()
rows = stringToList(content)

header = rows[0]
data = rows[1:]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
print(df)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how your solution is specific to Colab though? This should work in vanilla Jupyter, too?

Comment: @Wayne my solution is not specific to Colab. I believe the issue is that his Colab's pandas version uses a different logic to parse csv than other newer pandas versions. My code parses csv manually without using 3rd party libraries and then importing it into pandas, this would resolve his original issue instead of working around by using jupyter.