# Managing empty features/nulls when parsing and converting a raw geojson string to geodataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geojson, geopandas

I have a pandas dataframe with geojson data embedded within a column similar to the example below:

```
# Test data frame
data = {'Geojson': ['{"geometry": {"coordinates": [[[24.950899, 60.169158], [24.953492, 60.169158],[24.953510, 60.170104],[24.950958, 60.169990]]],"type": "Polygon"},"id": 1,"properties": {"GlobalID": "84756blabla","NAME": "Helsinki Senate Square","OBJECTID": 1,"OBS_CREATEDATE": 1641916981000,"OBS_UPDATEDATE": null, "Area_m2": 6861.47},"type": "Feature"}'],'Name': ["Helsinki Senate Square"], 'Type': ["Polygon"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head()
...
    Geojson Name    Type
0   {"geometry": {"coordinates": [[[24.950899, 60....   Helsinki Senate Square  Polygon
```

If I simply wish to convert this example to a geodataframe this code works fine:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features([json.loads(feature) for feature in test_features])
```

Most of the time, this code works just fine, however, I have lately started getting this error message:

```
File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py:635, in GeoDataFrame.from_features(cls, features, crs, columns)
    632 if hasattr(feature, "__geo_interface__"):
    633     feature = feature.__geo_interface__
    634 row = {
--> 635     "geometry": shape(feature["geometry"]) if feature["geometry"] else None
    636 }
    637 # load properties
    638 properties = feature["properties"]

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapely/geometry/geo.py:92, in shape(context)
     90 else:
     91     ob = context
---> 92 geom_type = ob.get("type").lower()
     93 if "coordinates" in ob and _is_coordinates_empty(ob["coordinates"]):
     94     return _empty_shape_for_no_coordinates(geom_type)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

This would suggest that there are null values within the geojson series, so the solution is probably simple, but I need a way to check and clean such values from the series before parsing. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: It works fine for me. But maybe you can share a minimal working example including imports etc. then I can tell you if I did something different

Comment: Hi @NightTrain, thanks for your feedback. Yeah the current code actually works. I suspect it's because the current data actually has values that are not in a neat geoJson format, but rather as a (possibly somewhat botched) Json, which is where the error message is coming from. I'm actually looking at cleaning the data earlier on in the workflow, but it might be useful to know how to manage/clean/eliminate non-geoJsons before iteration?

Comment: P.S. The code above is of course a massively simplified example, current can't post an example of the dodgy data since I don't know where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the following question:
[How to read a CSV file having JSON array inside to get Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77821594/22642861)

The answer has a way to parse JSON to string without using libraries. Use that in your code before you pass the data anywhere. In some scenarios, it could be better to handle parsing manually like this example because that would avoid parsing errors.